# Is there a way to read a har log using BMP

Tags: browsermob

I am using BMP to generate har logs using BMP. Now I want to read the log file using BMP . Is this possible or I will have to use another api such as HarLib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BrowserMob Proxy is really just a simple proxy with some test-friendly enhancements, so it can't be used to read or render HAR contents. There are some easy-to-use and functional open-source HAR viewers such as [HAR Viewer](http://www.softwareishard.com/har/viewer/) and [Chrome HAR Viewer](http://ericduran.github.io/chromeHAR/). The HAR file is valid JSON, so if you just need to read it, you can pretty print it using any JSON formatter.